# Error when calling perform operation on apollo ios

Tags: ios, apollo, podfile, apollo-ios

here my code in swift:

```
mutation = LoginMutation( email: "sample@gmail.com",password: "pa$$w0rd")

ApolloManager.shared.apollo.perform(mutation: mutation, resultHandler: { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let graphQLResult):
                    if let data = graphQLResult.data {
                        print("Token: \(data)")
                    } else if let errors = graphQLResult.errors {
                        print(errors)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
            }
        })
```

I get an error in the generated file and here is the error

> Instance method 'perform(mutation:publishResultToStore:context:queue:resultHandler:)' requires that 'LoginMutation' conform to 'GraphQLMutation'

btw I used pod file to add some references as I followed the documentation.
here is in my podfile:

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ProjectName' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AhenteNew
  pod 'Apollo'
  pod 'Apollo/SQLite'
  pod 'Apollo/WebSocket'

end
```

I used apollo-ios-cli to generate my API but I'm not sure why it is not running. if I made the project using the podfile the error showed while using the package dependencies the program worked fine. I don't know why the error saying cannot conform. please give the solution for this.

PS: here is my code in apollo-codegen-config

```
{
  "schemaNamespace" : "ProjectAPI",
  "input" : {
    "operationSearchPaths" : [
      "**/*.graphql"
    ],
    "schemaSearchPaths" : [
      "**/*.graphqls"
    ]
  },
  "output" : {
    "testMocks" : {
      "none" : {
      }
    },
    "schemaTypes" : {
      "path" : "./ProjectAPI",
      "moduleType" : {
        "swiftPackageManager" : {
        }
      }
    },
    "operations" : {
      "inSchemaModule" : {
      }
    }
  },
  "schemaDownloadConfiguration": {
      "downloadMethod": {
          "introspection": {
              "endpointURL": "<myendpoint>",
              "httpMethod": {
                  "POST": {}
              },
              "includeDeprecatedInputValues": false,
              "outputFormat": "SDL"
          }
      },
      "downloadTimeout": 60,
      "headers": [],
      "outputPath": "./ProjectName/graphql/schema.graphqls"
  }
}
```

using terminal I used these code:

```
(base) <dir> % ./apollo-ios-cli fetch-schema
(base) <dir> % ./apollo-ios-cli generate
```

any answer will be appreciated.